# Generating Codecov reports with Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci, codecov

Codecov is failing to process the code coverage reports. It appears to upload successfully but gives the error: "There was an error processing coverage reports".

My project is already successfully integrated with Travis-CI. I am just trying to post my code coverage reports to Codecov.

It is a public project so it doesn't need a token for Codecov.

I have nothing but a sample test in this project so far. I am trying to make sure this integration works before moving forward.

I have enabled code coverage in the schema editor and when I run the tests in Xcode I can see it is generating code coverage reports.

Do I need to integrate with Slather to format my reports before sending them to Codecov?

Could the paths to my files be wrong?

```
# travis.yml

language:
  - swift
osx_image: xcode10.2
script:
  - xcodebuild -scheme Healthy -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=12.2' -enableCodeCoverage YES build test
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

```
2.80s$ bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
  _____          _
 / ____|        | |
| |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __
| |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /
| |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /
 \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \_/
                              Bash-8a28df4
==> Travis CI detected.
    project root: .
--> token set from env
    Yaml not found, that's ok! Learn more at http://docs.codecov.io/docs/codecov-yaml
==> Processing Xcode reports via llvm-cov
    DerivedData folder: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
    hint Speed up Swift processing by using use -J 'AppName' (regexp accepted)
    hint This will remove Pods/ from your report. Also https://docs.codecov.io/docs/ignoring-paths
    + Building reports for Healthy framework
    + Building reports for HealthyTests xctest
    -> Running gcov for Obj-C
==> Running gcov in . (disable via -X gcov)
==> Python coveragepy not found
==> Searching for coverage reports in:
    + .
    -> Found 2 reports
==> Detecting git/mercurial file structure
==> Appending build variables
    + TRAVIS_OS_NAME
    + TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION
==> Reading reports
    + ./HealthyTests.xctest.coverage.txt bytes=768
    + ./Healthy.framework.coverage.txt bytes=417
==> Appending adjustments
    http://docs.codecov.io/docs/fixing-reports
    + Found adjustments
==> Gzipping contents
==> Uploading reports
    url: https://codecov.io
    query: branch=master&commit=a88333de1e49b8ba01ea8afe1106eb4ebab45daf&build=22.1&build_url=&name=&tag=&slug=dcortright%2FHealthy&service=travis&flags=&pr=false&job=215842516
    -> Pinging Codecov
https://codecov.io/upload/v4?package=bash-8a28df4&token=[secure]&branch=master&commit=a88333de1e49b8ba01ea8afe1106eb4ebab45daf&build=22.1&build_url=&name=&tag=&slug=dcortright%2FHealthy&service=travis&flags=&pr=false&job=215842516
    -> Uploading
    -> View reports at https://codecov.io/github/dcortright/Healthy/commit/a88333de1e49b8ba01ea8afe1106eb4ebab45daf
```

All I am seeing on my Codecov page is "There was an error processing coverage reports".

Comment: Please share the coverage report, you are trying to parse :-)